# How to catch submiting of form outside of submit button?

Tags: javascript

Is ther a way (and if, how to do this) to catch form submit action of user via javascript puting the js code outside of form?

Example: There is form on my webpage from external provider. I want to catch it as google analytics goal and send it as event. Thus, i need to add custom js code to "hack"/sniff when the button is pressed.

Comment: Seach for `onsubmit` or "submit event". jQuery - which need not be used - trivially exposes this as [`$(form).submit(callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the form is in an iframe or not. If it is, there's no way accessing it.
If however the form is part of the DOM of **your** page, you can listen to the submit event using:

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    _trackEvent(...)
});
```

Comment: +1 because uses pure javascript. It looks nobody realized that question didn't include `jquery` tag

Comment: I didn't even notice...just not so fond of jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should (be able to) hook an onsubmit on the form. You can do it right after the page has loaded; use jquery for example.

```
$("#someForm").on("submit", function()  {..... }) ;
```

If this is not answering you, let's hear the question again with more details :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input[type=submit]').on('click, function (){
    // set your var
});
```

That is, of course, if the form is actually part of the DOM and not in an iframe.

Comment: Actually, I like dkellner's solution better. Should take into account that the form had already been validated and is being submitted.